# Equation of a circle with following conditions

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Say I have a circle with radius $r$ and center $(c_1,c_2)$. What values for those constants makes the circle intersect the points $(-a,0)$ and $(a,0)$ and the upper plane part of the circle has length $l$? My attempt begins by setting $c_1 = 0$ since I figure the circle must be symmetric about the y-axis. However, after this I am having trouble determining $r$ and $c_2$.

Answer (score 1):

To start,
the equation of the circle 
(writing $(c, d)$
instead of
$(c_1, c_2)$),is
$(x-c)^2+(y-d)^2 = 
r^2$.

Since it goes through
$(a, 0)$
and
$(-a, 0)$,
$r^2
= (a-c)^2+d^2
= (-a-c)^2+d^2
$.
So
$a^2-2ac+c^2+d^2
=a^2+2ac+c^2+d^2
$
or,
subtracting,
$4ac=0$.
If $a \ne 0$,
then $c = 0$,
so the circle is
$x^2+(y-d)^2 = r^2$.

Also,
$r^2 = a^2+d^2$
so the circle is
$x^2+(y-d)^2 = a^2+d^2$.

The part in the upper plane
is the part above
$y = 0$.
Since the circle
passes through
$(-a, 0)$ and
$(a, 0)$,
the part of the circle
in the upper plane
passes through
these points
and,
setting $x=0$,
$(y-d)^2
=a^2+d^2
$
or
$y = d+\sqrt{a^2+d^2}$
(we use the positive root since we want
$y > 0$
for the upper plane).

The final step would be
to get an expression 
for the length of this 
arc of the circle
(in terms of $a$ and $d$),
set this expression equal to
$l$,
and solve for $d$
in terms of $a$ and $l$.

There may be
an easy way to do this,
but I don't see it
off the top of my head,
so I'll leave it at this.